# OpenGL ES/2.0: scope of glEnableVertexAttribArray?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I think - as I googled around, searched stackoverflow, and didn't find a clear answer - we need to clarify for the future: what is the exact scope of glEnableVertexAttribArray?

What do I mean exactly?  Well, we know: Uniform state is bound to the shader program.  So calling `glUseProgram(X)` (X > 0) will also set all used uniforms to either their default value (except on ATI), or the value we provided earlier via `glUniformXXX()` when that same program was active.  So my answer to my question like "what is the exact scope of glUniform" would be "every use of one specific shader program".

Now I have the situation that a Mesh may consist of multiple sets of buffer objects.  The pseudocode of rendering looks like this:

```
mat = mesh->getMaterial;
mesh->overrideUniforms;
mat->prepareGL;  // call glUseProgram, update changed Uniforms, bind textures
mesh->render;
```

Now `mesh->render` obviously deals with binding Attributes and drawing.  In case a mesh has multiple sets of buffers, it'd look like that (assuming each buffer object set contains all data for all attributes/one render pass):

```
for_each(set_of_bufferObjects)
    bindBufferObjects
    for_each(Attribute)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray
        glVertexAttribPointer
    glDraw
```

If the scope of enableVertexAttribArray was f.e. "every use of program X", I could spare those `glEnableVertexAttribArray` calls, as long as I enabled the array before (when program X was in use for the first time).

If on the other hand the scope was "during one specific program use", I could set them up once within `mesh->render` and then forget about them.  This would particularly explain why I don't suffer side-effects from not disabling any VAAs.

So is anybody out there enlightened to know which piece of GL state the glEnableVertexAttribArray belongs to?

P.S.: I'm explicitly asking for gl/es 2.0, as there are no VAOs by spec!  So please don't answer "just use VAOs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This state is global. Not related to the program state at all.

Edit: I just noticed the last paragraph of your question. So to the original poster, please ignore the part below, since you did not want to hear about VAOs. ;) I'll leave it there, just in case it helps somebody else.

Full OpenGL, as well as OpenGL ES 3.0, have an additional object type called Vertex Array Object (often abbreviated as VAO). This allows you to store all the setup state for a given set of vertex buffers in an object, and switch to the set of state with a single `glBindVertexArray` call. If you use this feature, the scope of the state becomes the VAO.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very clear.
What would happen with this scenario: at first a shader renders a mesh, it has 4 attributes enabled. We don't disable VertexAttributeArrays. Next another shader with only 2 active and enabled attributes renders some other geometry. I spared disabling attributes #2 and #3 - what does GL do?

Comment: That's a very interesting question. Functionally, I don't believe it does any harm, even though I couldn't find this specifically mentioned from some browsing through specs. I think having unused attributes enabled could potentially hurt performance. But that would be very dependent on the hardware interface and the driver implementation. I wouldn't expect it to be very substantial, if anything at all. Still, intuitively, I would recommend disabling unused vertex attributes.